# Consultar informação de um site

Tags: javascript

Presciso consultar o site  http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1 e pegar o valor que está em `meta name="member_count" content="53"` nesse caso 53

Tentar ver se consigo me explicar melhor.

Eu quero fazer um JS que consiga obter o numero de membros do link que postei a cima

Assim eu pretendo que eu consiga ter essa informação e possa manipular esse valor

O objectivo é conseguir exibir no meu site o numero de membros do grupo que mostra no link postado

Qual o melhor método de fazer isso?

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição `XMLHttpRequest` mas não obtive sucesso

```
  function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new
        ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        } 
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1",true);

    xmlhttp.send(); 
}

<input type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Tenta melhorar sua pergunta, não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Já tentou usar `document.write()` para ter certeza de que ele está recuperando a informação desejada?

Comment: tem a pagina http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1  e eu queria conseguir uma forma de tirar dela a informação 53 que é o numero de membros

Comment: nao retorna nada o xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: Você não vai conseguir. O servidor que você esta tentando acessar não permite CORS. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1?_=1418733119899. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Não existe forma de eu capturar a informação do numero de membros ?

Comment: Se o site não permitir CORS, então a única forma será usando uma abordagem no lado do servidor, ou então instalando algo no cliente: extensão do navegador ou então um servidor HTTP.

Comment: Em LSL eu Fiz um llHTTPRequest() ao site http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1 e consegui obter essa informação. O problema é que se eu usar LSL eu tenho de enviar a informação para um PHP e guardar em base de dados. Então eu procurei usar JS do mesmo modo que usei o LSL para obter o mesmo dado. http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/World_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CORS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) é um mecanismo que permite com que recursos de um servidor sejam acessados de uma página em outro domínio além do domínio original. Isso acontece para evitar justamente o que você esta tentando fazer e preservar os recursos do servidor, como bandwith e processamento (que no fim das contas custam dinheiro).

Alguns sites habilitam CORS, por exemplo, a [API do stackoverflow](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/44079?order=desc&sort=activity&site=pt.stackoverflow) e do [github](https://api.github.com/users/facebook), mas quando isso acontece geralmente eles sempre limitam a quantidade de requests que você pode fazer, também para evitar abusos.

O site que você esta tentando pegar a informação não permite CORS: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://world.secondlife.com/resident/24e6998d-7bf2-4d03-b38b-acf8f2a21fc1?_=1418‌​733119899. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Essa limitação não é imposta se você acessar SERVIDOR-SERVIDOR, como você mesmo constatou.

A solução para você seria implementar no seu servidor um proxy para comunicação com este site. Não necessariamente você precisa armazenar esta informação em banco de dados.

**LEIA TAMBÉM:**

1- [Política de mesma origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem)
2- [JSONP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: como poderia implementar um proxy para resolver o problema? Mas Finalmente entendo porque não posso usar o javaScript pois o site tem defesa e não permite que o consulte.

Comment: Isso é específico da linguagem de programação e dos frameworks que você está utilizando no backend, mas de maneira genérica você precisa fazer uma requisicao ajax no SEU servidor, o seu servidor rodando PHP faz uma requisicao no servidor do second life, que retorna o HTML da pagina. Via PHP você faz o parsing do HTML e retira a informação relevante e então você retorna a requisição ajax para o browser, contendo o que você precisa. Os detalhes da implementação disso eu desconheço pois nunca trabalhei com php.